# Node parsing csv to JSON adds unintended quote

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, parsing

Why is there always a single quote around my first key in each object?
Like this: `'ObjNr': '2022-15-06#1'`,
Even if I add a new first column it will always chose the first and add those quotes.
Any way to avoid this?

```
ObjNr;Brand;Model;Manufactured;kW;Price
2022-15-06#1;Mercedes;EQS-450;2022;363;94000
2022-15-06#2;Mercedes;EQA-350;2021;295;43556
```

```
app.post('/testcsv', uploadCSV.single('car_csv'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let csvJson;
    const csvData = req.file.buffer.toString();

    // Parse CSV data to JSON; first row is header;
    csv.parse(
      csvData,
      { delimiter: ';', columns: true},
      async (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('CSV parsing error:', err);
        } else {
          csvJson = data;
          console.log(csvData);
          console.log(csvJson);
          res.status(200).send(csvJson);
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    'ObjNr': '2022-15-06#1',
    Brand: 'Mercedes',
    Model: 'EQS-450',
    Manufactured: '2022',
    kW: '363',
    Price: '94000'
  },
  {
    'ObjNr': '2022-15-06#2',
    Brand: 'Mercedes',
    Model: 'EQA-350',
    Manufactured: '2021',
    kW: '295',
    Price: '43556'
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you update full code to reproduce your JSON output?

Comment: That is not JSON, which uses double quotes around property names and other strings.